# Android Studio: E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-device-manager

I have a strange problem with my Android Studio/AVD.

So I write a simple code in AndroidStudio just with a TextView telling to input smth in a TextField, and a button to log the input to the logcat -> when I run the app, AVD opens and loads normally but in the Logcat it keeps on printing new and new messages even when my App is fully loaded. 
Of all these messages the following two lines are bothering me most:

E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module 
W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1

I found some other threads about similar problems, but it was never quite the same and the solutions didn't work me as well. (The last thing i would like to mention: the apps i programmed so far (really simple ones) all worked despite this error but I think that something must be wrong if it keeps showing me this!)

Someone knows what to do?

Comment: Have you tried to just create another emulator?

Comment: Yep i already tried a variety of different Emulators with different API levels, but i get the error all the time. Could this error occur beccause I'm working on a quite slow laptop?